# Puppeteer returns Arabic characters instead of English

Tags: puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer library to scrape some data from a web page but it returns sometimes weird characters. I have set already browser and page options like below. The weird part of that is not happening always. What could be the cause of that?

For example, I got this "چای خونه" instead of "Tea Room".

```
//I set these options for the headless browser
 args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-notifications",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--lang=en-US,en-GB,en"
      ]

//I set also http 'Accept-Language' header like this way
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
      });

// the function grabbing text from an html element
      grabElementText(element) {
        if (element) {
          return element._page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, element);
        }
      }
```

Comment: btw چای خونه also means tea room!

Comment: @AbuBakarKhan I know but I need "tea room" and when I opened the page I see "Tea Room" not the Arabic letters. The question is why I get that Arabic letters?

Comment: @leo are you located in a country with that language?

Comment: @hardkoded No, I am not in an arabic country.